# how to calculate the input values from a range slider dynamic values .?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing some issues in jquery .. actually I have ionrange slider ..I am getting the values from that slider.. and now I have to use that values and put some conditions on it using if else statements(5-7 conditions) and show them in another input filed.. but I am not getting the required values.

For example, when the value of range slider is 0-100 then the rate is 22 and then total amount is rate*100 ...when the value is 101-500 then the rate is 21$ its show rate and then total amount is rate*500 and so on..

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-md-4 price-details  ">
        <div>Number of Students </div>
        <input type="text" maxlength="4" value="0" id="rangeValue-p" readonly class="inp val-p js-from "/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 price-details">
        <div>Price per Student per Month  </div>
        <input type="text" maxlength="4" value="0" id="rvps" readonly class="inp rvps-p"/><span>$</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 price-details">
        <div>Total Cost Per Month  </div>
         <input type="text" maxlength="4" value="0" id="totalAmount" readonly class="inp t-p"/><span>$</span>
    </div>
</div>



$("#rangeValue-p").on("change", function() {
    var rv_p =document.getElementById("rangeValue-p");
    var rate_p=0;
    var totalAmount_p=0;
    if (rv_p>=0 && rv_p<=100) {
      rate_p=22;
      $(".rvps-p").val(rate_p);
      totalAmount_p=rate_p*100;
      $(".t-p").val(totalAmount_p);
    }
    else if (rv_p>=101 && rv_p<=500) {
      rate_p=21;
      $(".rvps-p").val(rate_p);
      totalAmount_p=rate_p*500;
      $(".t-p").val(totalAmount_p);
    }
    else if (rv_p>=501 && rv_p<=1000) {
      rate_p=20;
      $(".rvps-p").val(rate_p);
      totalAmount_p=rate_p*1000;
      $(".t-p").val(totalAmount_p);
    }
    else if (rv_p>=1001 && rv_p<=1500) {
      rate_p=19;
      $(".rvps-p").val(rate_p);
      totalAmount_p=rate_p*1500;
      $(".t-p").val(totalAmount_p);
    }
    else if (rv_p>=1501 && rv_p<=2000) {
      rate_p=18;
      $(".rvps-p").val(rate_p);
      totalAmount_p=rate_p*2000;
      $(".t-p").val(totalAmount_p);
    }
    else if (rv_p>=2001 && rv_p<=2500) {
      rate_p=17;
      $(".rvps-p").val(rate_p);
      totalAmount_p=rate_p*2500;
      $(".t-p").val(totalAmount_p);
    }
    else if (rv_p>=2501 && rv_p<=3000) {
      rate_p=16;
      $(".rvps-p").val(rate_p);
      totalAmount_p=rate_p*3000;
      $(".t-p").val(totalAmount_p);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Need more to go on here really. How about putting up what you have in a plnkr or similar with more of the code vs this snippet. What is actually not working: is it that rv_p is not the slider value you expect or something further down in the logic...

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var rv_p =document.getElementById("rangeValue-p").value;
```

instead of

```
var rv_p =document.getElementById("rangeValue-p");
```